# Getting 'Provider is not enabled | ProviderError{provider='network'}' on calling 'tracker.startListening();' even when WiFi is enabled

Tags: android, android-location, locationmanager

I'm using [this](https://github.com/quentin7b/android-location-tracker/) library and trying to retrieve current location coordinates like this:

```
settings =
                new TrackerSettings()
                        .setUseGPS(false)
                        .setUseNetwork(true)
                        .setUsePassive(true)
                        .setTimeBetweenUpdates(30 * 60 * 1000);

        tracker = new LocationTracker(getBaseContext(), settings) {
            @Override
            public void onLocationFound(Location location) {
                // Do some stuff
                currentLatDouble = location.getLatitude();
                currentLngDouble = location.getLongitude();
            }

            @Override
            public void onTimeout() {

            }
        };
        tracker.startListening();
```

but, I'm getting this error:

```
W/LocationTracker: Provider (network)
                   fr.quentinklein.slt.ProviderError: Provider is not enabled | ProviderError{provider='network'}
```

Isn't WiFi a network provider or do I need to write some code related to `LocationManager` too?

Please let me know what is wrong here.

Comment: check https://github.com/quentin7b/android-location-tracker/issues/19

Comment: @Nas yeah, I have opened an issue there also.

Comment: in that library it has android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION only try it with adding permission for wifi state access

Comment: @Nas getting the same error even after adding `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Added the following permission in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
Allows applications to open network sockets.
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
Allows an app to access approximate location.
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
Allows an app to access precise location.
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
Allows applications to access information about networks.
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
Allows applications to access information about Wi-Fi networks.
```

Additionally

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location.network"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
    android:required="false" />
```

Comment: are u running this in device or emulator? whats ur OS version?

Comment: I'm running it on a device

Comment: whats ur OS version? Is your wifi enabled?

Comment: android marshmallow and yes WiFi is enabled and I have already checked the permission and granted it.